# Why I don't have "Bootable" in cgdisk?

Tags: partitioning, android-x86

When I follow [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/tYdQUVC5IhA?t=2m38s), they have a "bootable" button to make bootable a partition.

I have this screen however:
[image]

So, what must I do to make bootable my 8 GB partition ?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `cgdisk` while the tutorial used `cfdisk`. The former is for GPT, the latter is for MBR.

GPT does not have a bootable flag.

So you can either redo the tutorial with the correct tool or hope that the GRUB boot manager (which is installed afterwards) is a recent enough version so it can deal with a GPT/BIOS combination.

Comment: Even If i have move down with the cursor, I still don't have "bootable" button

Comment: Heh, I missed that you had `cgdisk` while the tutorial used `cfdisk`. GPT doesn’t have a bootable flag.

Comment: Yes, but when I install it without thinking at it, I have "No medium partition found" after the installation

Comment: Well then it appears the installer can’t deal with GPT/BIOS. Just use the correct tool and follow the tutorial again. I’ve also updated my answer.